# LISP extract an element from a list only in a specific case

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, extract

The function i'm looking for has to return the index of the first , that is out of a pair of " ".

For example, with the sequence

> { " h i , a l l " : 3 , " h o w , i s " : " x " }
>
> '( #\{ #\" #\h #\i #\, #\a #\l ... )

The function should return 11, not 4 (first occurrence of comma) because it is between " ".

I tried with this:

```
(defun control-comma (x p)
  (cond ((eql (car x) #\")
         (control-comma (subseq x (+ (position #\" x :start (+ 1 p)) 1)) p))
        ((eql (car x) #\,)
         p)
        (t
         (control-comma (cdr x) (+ 1 p)))
        )
  )
```

Using x as list of input and p as a 0-parameter to count the position, but it doesn't work and seems to be far away from the solution i'm looking for.

Thank you for every suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of defining a complex function, I suggest you to use the predefined [`position-if`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pos_p.htm#position-if) operator:

```
(defun first-comma (string start)
   (let ((in-double-quote nil))
     (position-if 
       (lambda (x)
         (case x
           ((#\") (progn (setf in-double-quote (not in-double-quote)) nil))
           ((#\,) (not in-double-quote))))
      string
      :start start)))

CL-USER> (first-comma (coerce "{ \"hi, all\" : 3, \"how, is\" : \"x\" }" 'list) 0)
15
```

A more complex, recursive solution based again on the idea of scanning the input list one character at time, is given by the following function, where the state “inside double-quote” is encoded through a couple of recursive local functions:

```
(defun fist-comma (x pos)
  (labels ((looking-for-comma (x pos)
             (cond ((null x) nil)
                   ((eql (car x) #\,) pos)
                   ((eql (car x) #\") (looking-for-double-quote (cdr x) (1+ pos)))
                   (t (looking-for-comma (cdr x) (1+ pos)))))
           (looking-for-double-quote (x pos)
             (cond ((null x) nil)
                   ((eql (car x) #\") (looking-for-comma (cdr x) (1+ pos)))
                   (t (looking-for-double-quote (cdr x) (1+ pos))))))
    (looking-for-comma (nthcdr pos x) pos)))
```

Finally, note that in both the above functions one should take into account possible escaping of the double quote with appropriate means.

Comment: Nice use of position-if. (DouglasP: You may want to handle escaped double-quotes too).

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to not using setf? Can i call an external support function instead? My teacher wants us to not use setf, set, defparameter ecc... inside function unfortunately.

Comment: @DouglasP, the function is based on the idea of keeping a state variable which is true “inside” the double-quotes and false outside of them. I think it is not easy to maintain the structure of the solution and avoid at all side-effects. I'll think about it, but in my opinion the function should be completely changed and defined in a recursive way.

Comment: @DouglasP, I modified the answer to eliminate side-effects.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I second the use of position-if. Side effects are fine, as long as they are contained.